How to show $\phi:\Bbb A^2\to\Bbb A^4$ by $(t,u)\mapsto(t-tu,u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1))$ is finite and birational on to its image, but not an isomorphism?
Let $\phi:\mathbb{A^2_\mathbb{C}}\to\mathbb{A^4_\mathbb{C}}$
$(t,u) \mapsto (t-tu,u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1))$.
I just found $\phi^{-1}$ given by $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto (x_1+x_3,\frac{x_4}{x_4-x_2})$ in $U=\mathbb{A^4_\mathbb{C}} - V(x_4 - x_2)$ which prove that $\phi$ is birational.
To prove that $\phi$ is not isomorphism is enought to realize that $\phi$ is not injective, $\phi(0,0) = \phi(0,1)$
I have no idea how could I prove that $\phi$ is finite, so I would like you suggest to me some clues.

Let $Y$ be the closure of the image of $\phi$, and let $i:Y\to\Bbb A^4$ be the inclusion. The composite map $i\circ\phi: \Bbb A^2\to \Bbb A^4$ induces a map on coordinate rings $\Bbb C[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]\to\Bbb C[t,u]$ by sending $x_1\mapsto t-tu=t(1-u)$, $x_2\mapsto u(u-1)^2$, $x_3\mapsto tu$, $x_4\mapsto u^2(u-1)$. The variety $Y$ has ideal which is exactly the kernel of this map, so we can view the induced map on coordinate rings coming from $\phi:\Bbb A^2\to Y$ as the inclusion of the subalgebra $\Bbb C[t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1)]\subset \Bbb C[t,u]$.
This lets us bypass the ugly computations of determining what the ideal of $Y$ is, and it lets us figure out the rest of the problem fairly quickly. To see that $\phi$ is birational, it suffices to show that the induced map on fields of fractions associated to the inclusion $K(Y)=\Bbb C[t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1)]\subset \Bbb C[t,u]$ is an isomorphism, which is quick: $t(1-u)+tu=t$ shows that $t\in K(Y)$, and $tu/t = u\in K(Y)$ too, so in fact $K(Y)=\Bbb C(t,u)$ and we've demonstrated that these two varieties are birational.
To see that $\phi$ is not an isomorphism, it suffices to show that the inclusion $\Bbb C[t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1)]\subset \Bbb C[t,u]$ is not an isomorphism, i.e. it is not surjective. I claim $u$ is not in the image of the inclusion: if $u=p(t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1))$ for some polynomial $p$, then evaluating both sides at $(t,u)=(0,1)$ gives that $1=p(0,0,0,0)$, while evaluating both sides at $(t,u)=(0,0)$ gives that $0=p(0,0,0,0)$. (This also shows that $Y$ is not normal, since $u\in K(Y)$  and $u$ is integral over $K[Y]$ but not in $K[Y]$.)
We can show that this inclusion is finite in several ways. First, $t,u\in\Bbb C[t,u]$ are integral over $\Bbb C[t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1)]$, as $t=(t-tu)+(tu)\in \Bbb C[t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1)]$ while $u$ satisfies $X^2-X=u^2(u-1)-u(u-1)^2=u^2-u$. Alternatively, we we could use the fact that normalization for a finitely-generated algebra over a field is finite, but this is probably a bit strong for this situation. Thirdly, we can inductively show that we can generate every monomial: we can find two polynomials $p,q$ so that we can write $t^au^b=p(t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1))+u\cdot q(t(1-u),u(u-1)^2,tu,u^2(u-1))$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$. By writing $t^a=(t(1-u)+tu)^a$, it suffices to prove the claim for $a=0$; we'll show this by induction. The base cases of $b=0,1$ can be done by $p=1,q=0$ and $p=0,q=1$, while if we know the result for all $b_0<b$ where $b\geq 2$, we can write $u^b=(u^2(u-1))^i\cdot(u^2(u-1)-u(u-1)^2)^j+\cdots$ for $3i+2j=b$ and $\cdots$ of degree at most $b-1$, then our inductive hypothesis shows we can construct the correction term $\cdots$.

Could we prove the last part proving that $t$ and $u$ are integer in $\phi^*(Y)$? Using the birrational aplication we have that: $t  = t(1-u) + tu, u = (u^2(u-1)(u^2(u-1)-u(u-1)^2)^{-1}),$
so, $x_1+x_3-t=0$ and $x_4(x_4-x_2)^{-1} -u=0 $, but I dont know how could I conclude

@JesusBezaRios Sure, you could also show that $t$ and $u$ are integral over $K[Y]$. (It took me a second to figure out that's what you meant by "are integer".) $t=(t-tu)+tu$ is already in $K[Y]$, while $u$ satisfies the equation $X^3-X-u^2(u-1)=0$. (Actually, the minimal equation for $u$ is $X^2-X-(u^2(u-1)-u(u-1)^2)$.)
